# Who was the youngest Executive Producer?

Tags: film-industry, producer

I was reading an article from [Deadline](https://deadline.com/2019/06/stranger-things-gaten-matarazzo-host-executive-produce-hidden-camera-prank-show-netflix-prank-encounters-1202632745/?fbclid=IwAR0fswBssRhJ9xD9ISGOrMWrYBWB8xjh2cnXju2SGTLdlsRH1IzhtdMwjZc) stating that the teenage *Stranger Things* actor, Gaten Matarazzo will executive produce a new 'hidden-camera prank' TV series for Netflix. Gaten Matarazzo is 16 years old.

This prompted me to wonder, ***who was the youngest Executive Producer to produce either a feature film or TV series?***

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this as 'trivia' [though I haven't yet]. Anyone care to expand on why it isn't?

Comment: I thought this falls in line with 'first' film kind of thing and/or history, but if it doesn't then that's fine. feel free to close it.

Comment: tbh, I'm easy with whatever the community decides. I still haven't personally vtc'd it. It's got a fair few upvotes already, so maybe mine is not the most popular opinion.

Answer (score 6):

*[Little](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8085790/)*, which coincidentally came out just two months ago (April 2019), was executive-produced by co-star Marsai Martin, who was 14 at the time of its release and just 13 when it went into production. Wikipedia, citing [this Grapevine article](https://thegrapevine.theroot.com/blackgirlmagic-black-ish-star-marsai-martin-set-to-be-1831621480), describes her as "the youngest executive producer in Hollywood history".

The same article cites Millie Bobby Brown as being executive producer for a film adaptation of the *Enola Holmes Mysteries* books, in which she will also star. Brown was 13 when the adaptation was announced, but she's now 15 and it's still in production, so I'd say Marsai Martin still holds the title.

There is still the possibility that someone younger than 14 produced a TV series, but to be honest, I find it highly remote.